# blender material stretching

Tags: materials, transforms

I downloaded a material (floor tiles) from blenderkit. When I add the material to the original cube  (middle) I get many small tiles (as I want), but i have problem when i scale the cube. On the left side I scale the cube first and then add materials, and on the right side I add material first and then scale. I would like the matereal to stay the same size when I scale the cube. How do I do this? [image]

Comment: You can scale in Edit mode, make sure that in the top right Options panel you have the Correct Face Attributes option enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale needs to be applied in order to "restore" the tile's proportions.

In object mode, with the cube selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then click on `Scale`. Alternatively, select `Object \ Apply \ Scale` in the top menu of the 3D viewport, to perform the same operation.

After doing this, you will notice that the scale is reset to `1` instead of `10` in the right-hand side menu, when the cube is selected, and the texture is back to expected size.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Took some time to understand that I had to scale in edit mode, then resett the scale in object mode, but i managed.